# Sending Data to Watch when iOS in background and Remote Notifcation Received

Tags: swift, apple-watch, wcsession

I am using `sendMessageData(_:replyHandler:errorHandler:)` to send information from iOS to Watch OS.  This works fine and also works fine when iOS is in the background per other apps where I have used this.  However, it does not seem to work when the iOS is in the background and the method was called as a result of a remote notification.

When iOS is on the background and a remote notification comes in iOS fires off some processes.  These all work but when it comes to it sending data to the watch, this is where it fails.  If the iOS app is in the foreground and the same remote notification comes in, sending data to the watch via the above method works.

Is there a way for iOS to send data to the watch when iOS is in the background AND the call is as a result of a remote notification that iOS handles?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchconnectivity/wcsession:

SendMessageData() is "intended for immediate communication between your iOS app and WatchKit extension"

In my app where I have a similar scenario, I use transferUserInfo() "to transfer a dictionary of data in the background" which is more reliable when transferring data, especially in the background.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You can use sendMessageData with iOS in the background so long as you have reachabllity.  I do this successfully in another app with the only difference here being the send is caused by an APN versus a background location update in my other app.  I do have reachability here.  Nonetheless, I tried it with the transfer process but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow your question in the following part - *"When iOS is on the background and a remote notification comes in iOS fires off some processes."*

Then remote notification appears it does not execute any of your code, so it will obviously not send data. If you used methods for handling remote notification in an extension, then that's probably possible. But you need to do that quickly and wrap your code into a background task. Otherwise, iOS will kill your app and you will never know what happened.

I suggest to write a simple logger that writes messages into a file and closes the file synchronously. It will allow to debug the things happening in background.

Once you will catch that the code is executed, note if the sending succeeds (use replayHandler or errorHandler). If you will not see log messages from these calls, then probably the iOS kills your app.

Then try to add background task before any work and end it correctly (plus implement expiration handler), and verify the logs again.